# beamer handout using custom theme leads to undefined control sequence of custom newcommand

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

I would like to create slides and a handout/manuscript using the same source files. For convenience, I have some shortcuts defined in my custom beamer theme, which seem to be skipped when translating the article. MWE:

```
% beamerthemeFOO.sty
\usetheme{Berlin}
\newcommand{\foo}{bar}
```

```
% main.tex
\usetheme{FOO}
\begin{document}
\frame{\foo}
\end{document}
```

```
% main.beamer.tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\input{main.tex}
```

```
% main.article.tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\setjobnamebeamerversion{main.beamer}
\input{main.tex}
```

`latexmk -pdf main.beamer.tex` does just fine. `latexmk -pdf main.article.tex` leads to:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \foo

l.3 \frame{\foo
               }
```

Changing `\newcommand...` for `\mode<all>{\newcommand...}` didn't help either. How do I fix that?

These macros are quite handy as they set several beamertemplates when inserting a custom-styled TOC frame, `\maketocframe`. As a hot fix, I manually add the TOC to my article:

```
\mode<presentation>{\maketocframe}
\mode<article>{\tableofcontents}
```

Though, I'm still very curious as to why that MWE is broken. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you combine your code into one concise MWE chunk that people can copy and paste for trouble shooting?

Comment: I don’t understand your question. The final code block is just to give people a direct hint that have the same problem. The first 4 code snippets are meant to be copied as is (the first comment gives the file name, all are to be put in the same directory) in order to reproduce the very same error message.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `\usetheme` is ignored in article mode. But given that you have a file named "beamerthemeFOO.sty" with the following contents

```
% beamerthemeFOO.sty
\usetheme{Berlin}
\newcommand{\foo}{bar}
```

you can just load it using `\usepackage{beamerthemeFOO}` (or even  `\input{beamerthemeFOO.sty}`).

So you can do:

```
% main.beamer.tex
\documentclass{beamer}

% [main.tex]
\usepackage{beamerthemeFOO}
\begin{document}
\frame{\foo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and:

```
% main.article.tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\setjobnamebeamerversion{main.beamer}

% [main.tex]
\usepackage{beamerthemeFOO}
\begin{document}
\frame{\foo}
\end{document}
```

[image]